# Ranking ignoring rows above a certain position (where a certain condition is first met)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get the ranks, ignoring the rows above a position when the condition is first met. For example, in my table below, I want to start ranking after the won=`true`. That means Alfred and Beth will not be ranked (or it can be ranked last whatever is easier)

I used `row_number() over partition by class, name order by won, score` . The result will be Christ = 1 but then Alfred = 2 and Beth =3. That is not I want. I want Christ =1, Dan =2 , Ethan=3, because their rows are below condition won=`true`

| class | name | score | won |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Alfred | 19 | False |
| A | Beth | 18 | False |
| A | Christ | 16 | True |
| A | Dan | 15 | False |
| A | Ethan | 14 | False |

Outcome wanted:

| class | name | score | won | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Christ | 16 | True | 1 |
| A | Dan | 15 | False | 2 |
| A | Ethan | 14 | False | 3 |

Any helps would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the correct ordering is by `score` you need to identify the *group* of rows before the first *True* value, where "before" is determined by score. One way is to use `row_number`:

```
with g as (
  select *,
  Row_Number() over(partition by class order by score desc)  
  - Row_Number() over(partition by class, won order by score desc) grp
  from t
)
select class, name, score, won,
  Row_Number() over(partition by class order by score desc) as "Rank"
from g
where grp > 0
order by class, score desc;
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5b163f85400a270341a789ce132cd65c)

Comment: thank you SO much. You don't know how much it helped me. This is such an elegant solution (almost cried when I read it). I checked with my data and it worked as charm.